# Overcome ESLint's `redundant-type-constituents` for Disposable interface

Tags: typescript, eslint, typescript-eslint

[TypeScript 5.2 introduced `Symbol.dispose`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-5-2.html) and the `Disposable` interface.

I tried to create my own `type` and have it intersect with it:

```js
type MyType = {
  foo: () => void;
} & Disposable;
```

But ESLint throws the following error:

> 'any' overrides all other types in this intersection type. eslint(@typescript-eslint/no-redundant-type-constituents)

I'm using the following packages versions:

```
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "6.11.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "6.11.0",
```

Would appreciate in help with that, without disabling that ESLint rule.

Comment: If the rule is incorrect, and you don't want to disable it, you'd have to raise it with the package maintainers. You can see it doesn't have any options: https://typescript-eslint.io/rules/no-redundant-type-constituents/#options.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is not with the [`plugin:@typescript-eslint/redundant-type-constituents` rule](https://typescript-eslint.io/rules/no-redundant-type-constituents). Notice that the lint complaint mentions `any`:

> ```
> 'any' overrides all other types in this intersection type.
> ```

That indicates that something is wrong with how [typed linting](https://typescript-eslint.io/linting/typed-linting) was configured in your project. typescript-eslint can't figure out the type of `Disposable`, so it thinks of it as `any`.

Make sure that:

- TypeScript (`tsc`) isn't reporting any type errors on that file. For example, is `Disposable` defined?
- `parserOptions.project` is set to something like `true` or `'tsconfig.eslint.json'` per [typescript-eslint's typed linting docs](https://typescript-eslint.io/linting/typed-linting) so that it can find the right TSConfig file

Comment: Aside: this is a good example of an ambiguity in the rule's reporting. IMO it should really include a mention that _"hey this is an error type, not a "true" `any`_. Filed https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/issues/8231. Thanks!